# Google App Engine Java on Eclipse can not connect to localhost

Tags: eclipse

Usage:  [options]

Options:
 --help, -h                 Show this help message and exit.
 --server=SERVER            The server to use to determine the latest
  -s SERVER                   SDK version.
 --address=ADDRESS          The address of the interface on the local machine
  -a ADDRESS                  to bind to (or 0.0.0.0 for all interfaces).
 --port=PORT                The port number to bind to on the local machine.
  -p PORT
 --sdk_root=DIR             Overrides where the SDK is located.
 --disable_update_check     Disable the check for newer SDK versions.
 --generated_dir=DIR        Set the directory where generated files are created.
 --jvm_flag=FLAG            Pass FLAG as a JVM argument. May be repeated to
                              supply multiple flags.

Answer (score 0):

I had come across similar problem while working with Google App Engine for Python-loalhost was not getting its connection established.

```
$fuser -k 8080/tcp
```

Try this in terminal/command prompt and restart localhost.

It worked for me. Hope it works for you also. Good luck!